SCANPST.exe missing Repair button *after* 3 iterations
I am running Outlook 2019 desktop app on Windows 10, and with Outlook closed, I ran SCANPST.exe, which reported errors.

I clicked on Repair to repair them, being advised to do so multiple times until no errors were reported
This worked ~3x, but during the 4th, I was not presented with a Repair button

What is causing the absence of the Repair button, and how can I get it back?

The closest to this I could find online is this, however the difference in my case is that I actually got the Repair button ~3x (the cited
solution cited there is no longer available online)


The Repair button seems to return if I open and close Outlook before running the next scan. I don't know if this will work for everyone, but it is one thing to try.
With further testing, I found that initial scans reports errors and the Repair button is provided.  Subsequent scans report no errors, but only minor inconsistencies.  The Repair button is not provided, even though the text says that Repair is optional.

It seems you're encountering an issue where the Repair button in SCANPST.exe is not appearing after multiple scans. This can happen due to various reasons, such as a corrupted installation of Microsoft Office, a damaged system file, or a conflict with another application.
Here are some steps you can try to resolve the issue:

Reboot your system to ensure that all temporary files are cleared and that the system is running optimally.
Run SCANPST.exe as an Administrator. Right-click on the SCANPST.exe file and select 'Run as Administrator' to see if this provides the Repair button.
Check for system errors using the System File Checker tool. You can do this by opening Command Prompt as an aAministrator and typing sfc /scannow.
Repair or reinstall Outlook. If the above steps do not work, you may need to repair or reinstall Outlook to fix any underlying issues.


What would #1 resolve? scanpst.exe is a standalone program that's manually run. What would #2 resolve? This isn't an Admin group related issue. What would #3 resolve? Not only does Sfc require running Dism first, it will only replace OS system files. For #4, what are the steps to repair Outlook & why would a reinstall be necessary when this is accomplished by an offline fix of Office (Outlook 2019 isn't a standalone program)? This answer comes across as having no idea how to actually resolve the issue and is throwing spaghetti at a wall

(Cont'd...) "This can happen due to various reasons, such as a... damaged system file... a conflict with another application." How would a corrupted system file cause a non-OS system file [scanpst.exe] to work correctly, repair corruption within a PST database file, then fail to show a GUI button within that program? (that's not how that works...) What conflict would scanpst.exe have with another application, especially considering Outlook has to be closed for it to scan and repair a .pst? What other program could be using the .pst? How would the offline scan then be performed?
